# How to let git-log color multiline placeholder values in format string?

Tags: git, colors, format, multiline, git-log

Given the following `git-log` command:

```
git log --max-count=1 --format='format:%C(cyan)%GG'
```

Only the first line of the `%GG` multiline placeholder value gets colorized. But I want to have the following text to be in the same color until the currently chosen color is reset by the next `%C(...)` statement. How can I achieve this?

I'm using Git version 2.1.0 on Fedora Desktop 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I came up with in the meantime is the following Bash script snippet:

```
function foobar {
  local -r committish="${1:-HEAD}"
  local -r tput_app="$(type -p tput)"
  if [[ -n $tput_app ]]; then
    local -r color_cyan="$("$tput_app" setaf 6)"
    local line=''
    while read -r line; do
      printf '%s\n' "$color_cyan$line"
    done < <(git log --max-count=1 --format='format:%GG' "$committish")
    printf '%s\n' "$("$tput_app" sgr0)"
  else
    git log --max-count=1 --format='format:%GG' "$committish"
  fi
}
```

This solution does not satisfy me because I generally prefer simple solutions to simple problems. But at least it works for me.